# Creating a structure array in C

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I am working on a programming assignment in C, which is about creating basic automation for cinema halls.

For holding data of halls, I define a structure like this:

```
typedef struct {
 char *hallName;
 char *movieName;
 seat** hallSeats;
 int studentCount;
 int fullFareCount;
 int totalSum;
 int width;
 int height;
}Hall;
```

So I am given a text file with commands and whenever I came up with a specific command, I should create a separate hall.  For that reason, I created another function for that.

```
Hall makeHall(char **temp)       //TEMP HOLDING THE LINES FROM FILE
 {
    int width = strToInt(temp[3]);
    int height = strToInt(temp[4]);

    char currentRowLetter = 'A';

    int currentRow;
    int currentSeat;

    seat **hall = malloc(sizeof(seat*) * width );

    for (currentRow=0 ; currentRow < width ; currentRow++)
    {
         hall[currentRow] = malloc(sizeof(seat) * height );

        for(currentSeat=0; currentSeat < height ; currentSeat++)
        {
            hall[currentRow][currentSeat].rowLetter = currentRowLetter;
            hall[currentRow][currentSeat].seatNumber = currentSeat + 1;
            hall[currentRow][currentSeat].seatTaken = ' ';
        }
        ++currentRowLetter;
    }

    Hall newHall;
    newHall.hallName = temp[1];
    newHall.movieName = temp[2];
    newHall.hallSeats = hall;
    newHall.width = width;
    newHall.height = height;

    return newHall;
}
```

Since I will have multiple halls, I created a Hall array in order to access them later.

```
    Hall *allHalls = malloc(sizeof(Hall) * 10);    /*Hall placeholder*/
```

While I iterate over the lines, I check commands and create halls or sell tickets.

```
Hall *allHalls = malloc(sizeof(Hall) * 10);                       /*Hall placeholder*/
FILE *f;
f = fopen("input.txt", "rt");
char *line = malloc (sizeof(char) * 200);   /*LINE HOLDER*/
int currentLineNumber = 0;
char *tmp;
int hallNumber = 0;

while (1) {     /*PARSING FILE*/
    if (fgets(line,200, f) == NULL) break;      /*FILE END CHECKER*/
    currentLineNumber++;
    tmp = strtok(line," ");
    char **temp = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 6);
    int currentWordNumber = 0;

    while(tmp != NULL)     /*PARSING LINES*/
    {
        temp[currentWordNumber] = malloc(strlen(tmp) + 1);
        strcpy(temp[currentWordNumber],tmp);
        tmp = strtok (NULL, " ");
        currentWordNumber++;
    }
    if(!strcmp("CREATEHALL",temp[0]))  
    {
        allHalls[hallNumber] = makeHall(temp); /*<<<<<<<PROBLEM*/
        hallNumber++;   
        printf("%d\n",hallNumber);
    }
```

Now that's the part I am lost at. Whenever I tried to access the array, the program crashes.

I thought it was a memory problem, so increased memory allocated by malloc for allHalls to 40 (even though it should not be a problem, since file only gives 3 different halls) and program no longer crashes, but instead overwrites the previous hall in the array.

I tried multiple solutions but none of them came out any good, so closest I get is this.

I did use java a lot before, so I am still stuck to OOP and pretty new to C.

EDIT 
Seat is defined as

```
typedef struct {
char rowLetter;
int seatNumber;
char seatTaken;

}seat;
```

also example createhall command is

```
CREATEHALL Hall_A Avatar 24 20
```

while the numbers at the end being width and height for hall

EDIT : [CODE](https://codeshare.io/evV9E)

Comment: Could you show us how an example file looks like? And how is `seat` defined?

Comment: Please provide the definition of `seat`.

Comment: You don't show how `hallNumber` is declared or initialized, and I see nothing to stop it from exceeding the number of entries in `allHalls`.

Comment: Advised to check that `currentWordNumber` does not exceed 5 (6 entries in `temp[]`).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Can't chase after bugs in multiple non-buildable program fragments.

Comment: sorry for that. Still new here. trying to improve question now

Comment: Could you format your code "Parsing file" properly? Would be better to make sure it's in order, doesn't look good at the moment.

Comment: `temp[currentWordNumber] = malloc(strlen(tmp) + 1);` - is that really what you meant to do? `strtok` function returns a pointer to the last token found in the string. A null pointer is returned if there are no tokens left to retrieve. I think you are allocating memory from the pointer's location till end of command, isn't it?

Comment: Memory management of `temp` and its parts is lousy (but no error seen that explains the crash).

Comment: @Elyasin, seen no error there. `tmp`is initialized from `strtok`

Comment: "_Whenever I tried to access to the array [the] program crashes_": Please show us where. I see no errors in your code that can explain a crash.

Comment: I send a link for code (hope that site works ) I tested it in another function. Somehow I feel like I am missing something so little.

Comment: I checked your code. Program does not crash at least... Can you show us the input file that makes yours program crash?

Comment: https://jpst.it/OIvb for input

Comment: I used 3 CREATEHALL commands. I am not sure if you are looking at the right spot for error... My feeling: BUYTICKET

Comment: Only thing I can think of, if error really occurrs at the line indicated, is that the compiler makes an error in the structure copy of the returned struct. What compiler are you using? Otherwise, check if `malloc` always succeeds.

Comment: I don't even call buyticket yet.. idk.

Comment: No you don't, but you do something in that `if` statement... `printf("%s\n", allHalls[0].movieName);`

Comment: I am using minGW with codeblocks

Comment: I think the timing of `free`ing the memory leads to `movieName` and other pointers in the `struct` to point to *illegal* memory addresses. Maybe allocate memory for the `char` pointers in the `struct`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the bug:

At the bottom of the `while(1)` loop in `main` you do a `free(allHalls);` so now there are no more halls and you get a segfault...

It was in the code you didn't show us:

```
while (1) {
    ...
    if(!strcmp("CREATEHALL",temp[0]))  
    {
        allHalls[hallNumber] = makeHall(temp); /*<<<<<<<PROBLEM*/
        hallNumber++;   
        printf("%d\n",hallNumber);
    }
    ....
    free(temp);
    free(allHalls);      // <-- there's your bug
}
fclose(f);
free(line);
```

Comment: As an afternote: You could have found this yourself if you had stepped the program through the debugger. Use your tools!